# Count of elements that form a group centralizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be an arbitrary group. Is it possible to measure a cardinality of $X = \{ \; x \in G \;\;|\;\; \exists\; y \in G, \;\; y \neq x :\;\; x^{-1} * y  \in C(g_0, g_1, ... , g_n) \; \}\;$, where $g_0, ..., g_n \in G$, $C(g_0, g_1, ... , g_n)$ is a centralizer of elements $(g_0, g_1, ... , g_n)$? Maybe we can say something about it, if we specify some additional requirements on the group $G$ (I'm currently interested in $S3$ and $A5$).

Thanks for any advise!

Comment: Excuse me if I am wrong, but it seems to me that there are only two possibilities: If the centralizer contains a non-trivial element $z$ then we have $X = G$ because for any $x \in G$ we can take $y = xz$. In case the centralizer is trivial, $X$ is obviously empty.

Comment: Thanks Matthias, you are right! Sorry for the question, it was a part of a proof and I formulated it incorrectly, but you gave me an idea to start reasoning from the centralizer variants, so I'll try to solve the problem by myself.